# Weinre can't open .js files

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, cordova, weinre

I'm working on a PhoneGap mobile app. I'm encountering the same issue while using debug.phonegap.com and a local weinre server. When I click on any *.js hyperlink on a Weinre "Elements" page, the "Resources" page/tab opens up, but it's completely empty. The application is running in an emulator started by ADT (eclipse with Android Development Tools plugin).

The screenshots below are a view at my code, the Weinre "Elements" page, and the Weinre "Resources" page. In this specific example, I'm trying to open up "ATNO.js" to debug. Shouldn't I be able to see something useful on the "Resources" tab?

Code Screenshot:
[image: Code Screenshot]
Weinre Elements Screenshot:
[image: Weinre Elements]
Weinre Resources Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This is still happening, anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jsHybugger - a JavaScript/HTML5/CSS debugger for Android? With the new jsHybugger version 1.2, you can change the javascript code of a mobile app without redeployment. Give it a try - http://www.jshybugger.org

Comment: accidental downvote. don't have enough rep to remove downvote. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging I found that you can debug files in your android mobile app with the Chrome Remote Debug, here is the link: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging